# Como configurar Zabbix

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

la cuestion es que necesito instalar Zabbix en una maquina virtual(en *Oracle VM VirtualBox*) con Centos 7 y poder usarlo en mi Windows 10. 
Ahora bien, logre instalar pero no se como tengo que configurarlo. 
Cree la Base de datos e modifique los archivos php.ini, zabbix_server.conf y zabbix.agentd.conf, pero no pude utilizar Zabbix.

Espero me puedan brindar una solucion.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: https://www.fosslinux.com/7705/how-to-install-and-configure-zabbix-on-centos-7.htm

Comment: Esa pagina fue la que use para instalarlo